# Check Liferay admin user Login

Tags: extjs, admin, liferay-6, user-permissions, spring-portlet-mvc

I used liferay 6.1, in my spring MVC portlet one button for only admin in jsp page.

so i want to do check that in controller if admin is login then only that button accessible otherwise no other user can access that.

jsp page all the datagrid content render with extJS so in my jsp all data with write in java script.So, How can we do that in that here is my image link i.imgur.com/Qwfbg2H.png

So can you tell me how can i check and implement that logged in user is admin .??

Answer (score 2):

You can use `permissionChecker.isOmniadmin()` to check if logged-in user is admin.

permissionChecker is implicit object you will get when you have statement `<theme:defineObject/>` with proper tld declared in your jsp.

e.g.

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/theme" prefix="theme" %>
<theme:defineObjects />
```

Comment: thats we can do if the code developed in jsp but in my jsp page all the datagrid content render with extJS so in my jsp all data with write in java script.So, How can we do that in that here is my image link http://i.imgur.com/Qwfbg2H.png

Comment: You would have mentioned this in question itself. By the way if you may have ajax call to portlet to check if user is admin